Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed on GPU for the `train()` function of HuggingFace `Seq2SeqTrainer`
I use the HuggingFace Transformer framework's Seq2SeqTrainer to fine-tune a pre-trained model. The codes run perfectly on the CPU but are unable to run on GPU (NVIDIA GeForce 4090). The following error occurs:

Assertion srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize failed

It is a common issue when using CUDA, but there are many causes of such errors. Therefore, I use a custom Seq2SeqTrainer to debug the index sizes. Here are the codes of my custom Seq2SeqTrainer:
class CustomSeq2SeqTrainer(Seq2SeqTrainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSeq2SeqTrainer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.step_count = 0  # Initialize a step counter attribute
        
    def training_step(self, model, inputs):
        self.step_count += 1 # Increment the step counter
        
        # Log tensor details for the first two steps
        if self.step_count <= 2:
            for k, v in inputs.items():
                if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                    print(f"Step {self.step_count} -- {k}: Shape={v.shape}")
                    print(f"Step {self.step_count} -- {k}: Tensor={v}")
                    
        elif self.step_count <= 10000:
            for k, v in inputs.items():
                if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                    print(f"Step {self.step_count} -- {k}: Shape={v.shape}")
                    
        return super(CustomSeq2SeqTrainer, self).training_step(model, inputs)  # Call the parent class's method

And here is the output when I run the trainer.train() which trainer is an instance of CustomSeq2SeqTrainer:
Step 1 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 1 -- input_ids: Tensor=tensor([[    2,   198,    66,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,     0,   278,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,  1037,   198,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        ...,
        [    2,    81,  1058,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,    81,  3238,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2, 18327,     0,  ...,     1,     1,     1]])
Step 1 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 1 -- token_type_ids: Tensor=tensor([[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])
Step 1 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 1 -- attention_mask: Tensor=tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])
Step 1 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 1 -- labels: Tensor=tensor([[    2,   887,    66,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2, 10741,  1029,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,   109,  1071,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        ...,
        [    2,    61,   246,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,    61,   887,  ...,     1,     1,     1],
        [    2,   255,     0,  ...,     1,     1,     1]])
Step 2 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 2 -- input_ids: Tensor=tensor([[   2,  406,  350,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2,  170,   89,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2,    0,    0,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        ...,
        [   2, 4785,    3,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2, 5733,  226,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2, 1117,    0,  ...,    1,    1,    1]])
Step 2 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 2 -- token_type_ids: Tensor=tensor([[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])
Step 2 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 2 -- attention_mask: Tensor=tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])
Step 2 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 2 -- labels: Tensor=tensor([[   2,  406,  114,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2,    0,  317,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2,    0,  537,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        ...,
        [   2, 4785,  963,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2,  905,  537,  ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   2, 1117,    0,  ...,    1,    1,    1]])
Step 3 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 3 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 3 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 3 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 4 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 4 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 4 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 4 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
 [ 4/103050 00:00 < 13:27:29, 2.13 it/s, Epoch 0.00/30]
Epoch   Training Loss   Validation Loss
Step 5 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 5 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 5 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 5 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 6 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 6 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 6 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 6 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 7 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 7 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 7 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 7 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 8 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 8 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 8 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 8 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 9 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 9 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 9 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 9 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 10 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 10 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 10 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 10 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 11 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 11 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 11 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 11 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 12 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 12 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 12 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 12 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 13 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 13 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 13 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 13 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 14 -- input_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 14 -- token_type_ids: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 14 -- attention_mask: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
Step 14 -- labels: Shape=torch.Size([8, 200])
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [64,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [65,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [66,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [67,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [68,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [69,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [70,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [71,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [72,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [73,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [74,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [75,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [76,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [77,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [78,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [79,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [80,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [81,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [82,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [83,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [84,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [85,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [86,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [87,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [88,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [89,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [90,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [91,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [92,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [93,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [94,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [186,0,0], thread: [95,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [187,0,0], thread: [32,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [187,0,0], thread: [33,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [187,0,0], thread: [34,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [187,0,0], thread: [35,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1290: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [187,0,0], thread: [36,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.

The thread value ranges from: [0, 0, 0] to [127, 0, 0].
The training ends with an error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

How can I resolve this GPU-only problem?

UPDATE
The same issue appears in GeForce 3090 GPU card as well.
UPDATE 2
I add 10000 to the model like this: resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer) + 10000) and the error becomes:

RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 58685]' is invalid for input of size 109896000


https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu — it is an indexing value not size issue, if you read the code. And i guess you don’t see the error in CPU code because that bounds checking isn’t performed

@talonmies how can I fix this issue? thanks.

It’s in the input data, from the looks of things

Try to loop through the inputs and then check their max input_ids against the max vocab id from your tokenizer, and also check length of input_ids against max length set by the model.

len(tokenizer) is 58685, max input_ids of training dataset (max(train_ds['input_ids']) and evaluation dataset are 58668 and 58260 respectively, which is smaller than the tokenizer's vocab size. Length of input_ids is truncated/padded to max_length during tokenization: tokenizer(inputs, return_tensors="pt", text_target=targets, padding="max_length", max_length=200, truncation=True)

by the way, the same code ran perfectly okay on Google Colab T4 GPU as well.
